# ECS volume sharing in multcontainer task

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have two containers node and nginx. Im trying to make nginx container refer to a directory inside node container.

As shown bellow I'm using -v to define volume called `public` for node container and refer it in the nginx container and it works fine, Im able to ls in the nginx container in app-public folder

**Node container**
[image]

**Nginx contaienr**
[image]

I'm trying to achieve this in ECS. I defined a volume in the task
[image]

specify the mount point in the node container

[image]

and specify the `volumes from` in the nginx container, `marketing-site-container` is the name of my node container.
[image]

JSON https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=f51bb2950416d5a06259a6acdc2caa33

This doesn't seem to work

Comment: Could you please include the task definitions you used in either json or yaml format? That's the easiest way of showing your volume mounting setup.

Comment: Looking inside of your task.json you don't define any top level volumes. That's your problem. "volumes": []